# Python: Ignore comma in a string while writing to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a Python dictionary that I am writing onto a csv file. 
The format of the dictionary is as follows:

```
{'title': u'A Preface to Democratic Theory.', 'year': u'1957'}
{'title': u'Joseph A. Schumpeter, Capitalism, Socialism, Democracy, New  York 1942', 'year': None}
```

The problem is the "comma" in the title. Since there is a comma in the key value, csv splits it into different cell. So I have Joseph A. Schumpeter in first cell , Capitalism in second cell and so on. 
Here is my code to write the csv file:

```
def make_csv(mydict):
    with open('mydata.csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=[""], delimiter=',')
    writer.writeheader()

    [f.write('{1},'.format(key, normalize(value))) for key, value in mydict.items()]
```

Can somebody help?

Comment: Why are you ignoring the writer object? If ou use `writer.writerow()` properly values with a comma will be quoted.

Comment: And why set `fieldnames=[""]`?

Comment: `writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=['title', 'year'])`, then `writer.writerow(mydict)`. Not re-opening the file each time would be helpful too; open the file *once*, create the `DictWriter` once, then just keep using that to write out `dict` rows.

Comment: @Martijin: I am writing in "append" mode because of which the titles were appended in every row. Thats why for now, I had left it blank

Comment: Just remove the `writer.writeheader()` call then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not specify the `fieldnames` and use the `DictWriter`'s `writerow` method.

You can skip `writeheader` if you don't need the header:

```
def make_csv(list_of_dicts):
    with open('mydata.csv', 'a') as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f,fieldnames=["title", "year"], delimiter=',')
        writer.writerows(list_of_dicts)
```

Pass the list of dicts as a parameter to your function and use the `writerows` method to write all the data at once.